# Publishing via someone else's account

Tags: app-store

I have a client who I made an app for, is it possible for me to publish via my developer account, but have the revenue from the app go to them? The client does not have a developer account, does he need one to have full control of the App on Appstore?

The main issue would be the payment, statistics and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to publish on your account but have the info, stats, and payments go to your client. If he wants to directly get the payments and info he would need his own account.

You can publish on your Dev account and then transfer the payments to him manually. Also there are several services which you could use to give him access to statistics (appfigures.com,  appannie.com etc).